# How can I prevent gson to try to parse value of my variable?

Tags: java, json, gson

Recently I've got an interesting problem with getting json string out of the object using gson library.

My object has a simple form:

```
class MyObject{
 public String myString = "{\"payload\":\"test\"}";

 setters & getters
}
```

The value of myString is a json string.

So when I'm trying to use

```
MyObject myObject = new myObject();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String payload = gson.toJson(myObject);
```

I got an exception saying:

Failed to process Expression Evaluation "json:payload".

So it looks like gson is trying to parse the value of the field in myObject, which is unexpected and weird.

How can I prevent gson to try to parse value of my variable?

Thanks,
Laura.

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me. You must be showing us something else. Post the full stack trace and your full class.

Comment: The code you've posted produces no errors. Either you're using some ancient version of Gson or there's something else going on. The actual stack trace would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyObject original = new MyObject();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String payload = gson.toJson(original); // generate json
    System.out.println(payload);
    MyObject recreated = gson.fromJson(payload, MyObject.class); // parse json
    System.out.println(recreated.myString);
}

static class MyObject {
    public String myString = "{\"payload\":\"test\"}";
}
```

prints

```
{"myString":"{\"payload\":\"test\"}"}
{"payload":"test"}
```

So I don't see what you're worried about. I get no errors.

> How can I prevent gson to try to parse value of my variable?

Do you want the value of `myString` in the generated json or not?

Answer (score 0):

If a field is marked `transient`, it is ignored and not included in the JSON.

Comment: I want it to be included in json. I don't want the value of the field to be parsed during the json forming.

Comment: So you want to be able to read it (`.fromJson()`) but not output it (`.toJson()`)?

Answer (score 0):

Gson can do this in a few ways, marking a field transient, using a custom DeserializationExclusionStrategy and usage of the @Expose annotation (although this annotation is the inverse of your use case)

That being said, your example case seems like it works fine.

see the section on the user guide. Full of useful stuff!
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

**Excluding Fields From Serialization and Deserialization**

> Gson supports numerous mechanisms for excluding top-level classes,
>   fields and field types.  Below are pluggable mechanism that allow
>   field and class exclusion. If none of the below mechanism satisfy your
>   needs then you can always use custom serializers and deserializers.
>
> Java Modifier Exclusion
>
> By default, if you mark a field as transient, it will be excluded.  As
>   well, if a field is marked as "static" then by default it will be
>   excluded. If you want to include some transient fields then you can do
>   the following:
>
> import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
>
> Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
>       .excludeFieldsWithModifier(Modifier.STATIC)
>       .create();
>
> NOTE: you can use any number of the Modifier constants to
>   "excludeFieldsWithModifier" method.  For example: Gson gson = new
>   GsonBuilder()
>       .excludeFieldsWithModifier(Modifier.STATIC, Modifier.TRANSIENT, Modifier.VOLATILE)
>       .create(); Gson's @Expose
>
> This feature provides a way where you can mark certain fields of your
>   objects to be excluded for consideration for serialization and
>   deserialization to JSON. To use this annotation, you must create Gson
>   by using new
>   GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create(). The
>   Gson instance created will exclude all fields in a class that are not
>   marked with @Expose annotation.

Comment: There's literally nothing wrong with the code as posted. Gson isn't going to try to do anything with the contents of `myString` during serialization.